# Unable to reach Bash Shell on 'docker attach'

Tags: git, nginx, docker, coreos, dockerfile

On the remote server, docker is running an image based off `nginx` with `Dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx

COPY ./ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

`docker ps` shows:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES
a71e45d5cd40        myUsername/myNginxWebsite:latest   "\"/bin/sh -c '/usr/   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp               sharp_fermi
```

After connecting to the remote server via SSH, running `docker attach <container_id>` shows the output of `nginx` and pressing `ctrl`+`q`, `ctrl`+`c`, `ctrl`+`p` does not get me to back to the bash shell.

Is it possible to get to the shell? I'll like to do something like a `git pull`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker exec -it <container-id-or-name> /bin/bash`

As per https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec -

> Usage: docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]
>
> Run a command in a running container
>
> -d, --detach=false         Detached mode: run command in the
>   background   -i, --interactive=false    Keep STDIN open even if not
>   attached   -t, --tty=false            Allocate a pseudo-TTY

Comment: Thanks, that got me into bash shell of the container. Do you know why `apt-get install git` gives `E: Unable to locate package git` and `sudo` gives `bash: sudo: command not found`?

Comment: Which nginx image are you using as a base? The official nginx images use Debian so `apt-get` should work fine. Try `who` at the CLI - you're usually logged in as root already.